# Deleting files from the Hadoop with pyspark (Query)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hadoop, pyspark

I'm using `Hadoop` for storing my data- for some data I'm using partitions, for some data I don't.
I'm  saving the data with `parquet` format using the pyspark `DataFrame` class, like this:

```
df = sql_context.read.parquet('/some_path')
df.write.mode("append").parquet(parquet_path)
```

I want to write a script that deletes an old data, with a similar way (I need to query this old data with filtering on the data frame) with `pyspark`. I haven't found something in the `pyspark` documentation...

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pyspark` is predominantly a processing engine. The deletion can be handled by `subprocess` module of raw python itself.

```
import subprocess

some_path = ...
subprocess.call(["hadoop", "fs", "-rm", "-f", some_path])
```

Comment: What if the host which the application is running does not have hadoop and it connects to a cluster?